# Adding null values to array in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, null

In a swift project I was able to do this easily. I have an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D's and CLLocationDistances

Here is the swift code (inside a PFQuery) It works just fine

```
if let returnedLocation = object["location"] as? PFGeoPoint
{                   
    let requestLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(returnedLocation.latitude, returnedLocation.longitude)                       
    self.locations.append(requestLocation)                  
    let requestCLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: requestLocation.latitude, longitude: requestLocation.longitude)
    let driverCLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)        
    let distance = driverCLLocation.distanceFromLocation(requestCLLocation)
    self.distances.append(distance/1000)
}
```

When I try to add them in Objective C to the locations and distance arrays I get an error because I'm adding an object without a pointer. What would be the best way to get around this? Thank you

Objective C code (they're both NSMutableArrays)

```
if (object[@"driverResponded"] == nil) {
    NSString *username = object[@"username"];
    [self.usernames addObject:username];
    PFGeoPoint *returnedLocation = object[@"location"];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D requestLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(returnedLocation.latitude, returnedLocation.longitude);
    //FIX!
    [self.locations addObject:requestLocation];
    CLLocation *requestCLLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:requestLocation.latitude longitude:requestLocation.longitude];
    CLLocation *driverCLLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:location.latitude longitude:location.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [driverCLLocation distanceFromLocation:requestCLLocation];
    [self.distances addObject:distance/1000];
}
```

Comment: Why not just add `requestCLLocation` to `self.locations` and pull the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` from it when you need it??

Comment: There is no `null` in your question as specified in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to store it as a `CLLocationCoordinate` doing this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D new_coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(returnedLocation.latitude, returnedLocation.longitude);
[self.locations addObject:[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:new_coordinate]];
```

Pull it back out like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [[self.locations objectAtIndex:0] MKCoordinateValue];
```

Comment: Thank you! And for the distances [self.distances addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:distance]]; seems to work too.

Comment: Glad it helped! Make sure to mark the answer correct so other people don't submit new ones!